# I need to find only the domain and not IP using preg_match_all

Tags: php, regex

I'm trying to call a text file and only grab the domain names and not the IPs showing at first.

```
103.246.245.253 my.test.com
103.6.86.209 www.test.com
104.131.236.104 test.test.com
107.170.182.78 ride.metrorock.test.com
107.182.176.204 mail.test.com
```

I only need the domains:

```
my.test.com
www.test.com
test.test.com
ride.metrorock.test.com
mail.test.com
```

Can anyone help me with the correct regex to find "random ip" "add space" to then use `(.*?)` to get the domain.

Example:

```
 preg_match_all('|(ip)(space)(.*?)|',$source,$sites);
```

Comment: Why the JavaScript tag — surely this is PHP? Why don't you just use `explode(' ', $line)[1]` for each line? https://3v4l.org/htvvI

Comment: or `preg_match_all('|\S+$|',$source,$sites);`

Comment: @AvinashRaj you'd need `'|\S+$|m'` to get all domains.

Comment: @cmbuckley: The lines above are most likely treated as separate input strings and the multiline flag is not necessary then.

Comment: @stribizhev if they're separate strings, then you wouldn't be using `preg_match_all`.

Comment: This will find IP, space, anything. https://regex101.com/r/vG6aO5/1

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure that your file is in the above format you can just use:

```
\S+$
```

Meaning multiple non-space characters at the end of a line.

---

However, if you want to be as precise as you described:

```
\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3} (.+)$
```

Now the first group will contain your domain.

Comment: Hi thanks I did try but it didn't work.

http://lumadis.be/regex/test_regex.php?id=2600

Comment: @pancho, I missed a slash in front of one of the `d`. Sorry about that, it should be fine now.

Comment: @pancho remember that you'll also need the `/m` modifier to match multiple lines.

Comment: |\S+$(.*?)| works but only find the end of a line. Can I use '|\S+$|m' with  (.*?)

Comment: @pancho: Looks like you just need [`|\S+$|m`](http://lumadis.be/regex/test_regex.php?id=2602). The `(.*?)` after `$` will never be found as in your case `$` is the end of the string.